# Laravel sql take top records and get it's field values average

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5

how can I be able to get top records e.g top 10 top 5 top 3, I've tried to use **AVG** on my query but it returns the whole average of a persons record.

**SQL**

```
if( !$field ) {
    $select = [
        DB::raw('AVG(sFieldGoalsPercentage) AS sFieldGoalsPercentage'), 
        DB::raw('AVG(sThreePointersPercentage) AS sThreePointersPercentage'), 
        DB::raw('AVG(sTwoPointersPercentage) AS sTwoPointersPercentage')
    ];
}

$player1 = DB::table('person_match_statistics')
    ->where('competitionId', $competitionId)
    ->where('personId', $player1Id)
    ->where('periodNumber', 0)
    ->orderBy('matchId', 'DESC')
    ->select($select)
    ->take($lastGame)
    ->get();
```

**Array**

```
0 => {#543 ▼
  +"sFieldGoalsPercentage": 0.56
  +"sThreePointersPercentage": 0.5
  +"sTwoPointersPercentage": 0.63
}
1 => {#536 ▼
  +"sFieldGoalsPercentage": 0.4
  +"sThreePointersPercentage": 0.4
  +"sTwoPointersPercentage": 0.4
}
2 => {#539 ▼
  +"sFieldGoalsPercentage": 0.38
  +"sThreePointersPercentage": 0.2
  +"sTwoPointersPercentage": 0.67
}
```

Comment: use group by clause

Comment: Top records of what? What's your table and what do you need from it?

Comment: top record of a user

Comment: don't use aggregates, that will calculate based on all rows and return a single row with the results. Use a simple `orderBy` and `take`

Comment: thanks @apokryfos, I'll try your suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`avg()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-avg) collection method. Get top ten records:

```
$player1 = DB::table('person_match_statistics')
    ->where('competitionId', $competitionId)
    ->where('personId', $player1Id)
    ->where('periodNumber', 0)
    ->latest('matchId')
    ->select($select)
    ->take(10)
    ->get();
```

Then count an average without executing any new queries using [`take()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-take) and [`avg()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-avg) collection methods. For example:

```
$top10 = $player1->avg('column');
$top5 = $player1->take(5)->avg('column');
$top3 = $player1->take(3)->avg('column');
```